# Solr Query behavior : Possible MultiPhraseQuery issue

Tags: java, search, solr, full-text-search

I have a field `productName_split` indexed with value "black iPhone 5c".

Search for "**5c**" or "**iphone 5c**" returns result.

But search for "**black iPhone 5c**" doesn't return any result. Following is `debugQuery` outcome:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">productName_split:"iPhone 5c"</str>
  <str name="querystring">productName_split:"iPhone 5c"</str>
  <str name="parsedquery">MultiPhraseQuery(productName_split:"iphone (5c 5) c")</str>
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">productName_split:"black iphone (5c 5) c"</str>
```

I am wondering what is the meaning of "(5c 5) c", is this causing the issue? Similar behavior happens with "**3GB**", "**500MB**" etc.

Schema for `productName_split`:

```
<fieldType name="text_split" class="solr.TextField"
            autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" omitNorms="true">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                    words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    preserveOriginal="1" splitOnNumerics="1" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                    words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"
                    splitOnNumerics="1" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

**Edit:** After searching more on this issue, I am suspecting on `MultiPhraseQuery`, how and when this kicks-in? I've provided `autoGeneratePhraseQuery="false"`, shouldn't this suppress formation of `MultiPhraseQuer`?